# What should I do if "except part" is not seen by python?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to make a Whatsapp message sender using selenium. I have a txt file that contains phone numbers I want to send a message to and everything is fine about it but the problem is my internet speed. It is not stable.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key,Controller
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.common.exceptions import UnexpectedAlertPresentException

with open(r"C:\Users\Resul\Desktop\numbers.txt") as f:
    lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(r"C:\Users\Resul\Desktop\numbers.txt")]

keyboard = Controller()
class WhatsappBot():

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.process()

    def process(self):
        for i in lines:
            print(i+ " " + "Done!")
            link = 'wa.me/{}'.format(i)
            self.driver.get("https://"+link)
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="action-button"]').click()
            time.sleep(3)
            try:
                waiter = WebDriverWait(self.driver,25).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]')))
                message_box = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]')
                for j in message:
                    message_box.send_keys(j)
                    for l in range(23):
                        keyboard.press(Key.space)
                        keyboard.release(Key.space)
                time.sleep(3)
                send_button = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[3]/button')
                send_button.click()
                time.sleep(8)

            except TimeoutException:
                print("Wait More!")
                time.sleep(10)

            except UnexpectedAlertPresentException:
                self.driver.switch_to.alert().accept()


wpbot = WhatsappBot()
```

Code is here. Since my internet connection is not stable, sometimes driver gives me alerts that say "You wanna leave?" because the message is not sent and the "except UnexpectedAlertPresentException" doesn't work. Eventhough I have that part, it still gives me that error.

```
    selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: None
Message: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : }
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.142)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=72.0.3626.69 (3c16f8a135abc0d4da2dff33804db79b849a7c38),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd change logic here a bit in Your whatsAPP bot:

**Option A**

Considering You're getting **UnexpectedAlertError**  each time after entering some keys in the input,  I'd recommend to check for alert every time You call *.send_keys(...)* method

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
self.driver.get("url")

send_button = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[3]/button')
send_button.click()

try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, 3).until(EC.alert_is_present(),
                                   'Timed out waiting for PA creation ' +
                                   'confirmation popup to appear.')

    alert = self.driver.switch_to.alert
    alert.accept()
    print("alert accepted")
except TimeoutException:
    print("no alert")
....
```

Summarizing, after each action: either click or sendKeys call, You're awaiting for the alert and accept it if it appears. Or handle exception and continue execution flow.

======
**Option B**

Try to debug and figure out the line of code that is more frequently throwing an exception. And wrap You input logic in try 
and catch more generic exception like:

```
  except Exception:
```

And inside of this catch block check whether any alert appeared and accept/dismiss if it appeared.

```
alert = self.driver.switch_to.alert
    if alert.is_displayed():
        alert.accept()
```

Hope this be helpful for You.

Regards,
Eugene